# Pass a function argument to dict?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

The following works in my current script:

```
item_dict = json_data
numOfKids = len(item_dict['contents']['rootFeature']['childFeatures'])
print(str(numOfKids))
while numOfKids > 0:
    numOfKids = numOfKids - 1
    assert 'handle' in json_data['contents']['rootFeature']['childFeatures'][numOfKids] 
    handleItem = json_data['contents']['rootFeature']['childFeatures'][numOfKids]['handle']
    print("Child : " + handleItem)
else:
    print("Done")
```

I am trying to move this to its own function using the following:

```
def validateChildren(json_data, parentPath):
    item_dict = json_data
    childList = item_dict + parentPath    
    numOfKids = len(childList)
    print(str(numOfKids))
    while numOfKids > 0:
        numOfKids = numOfKids - 1
        childPath = json_data + parentPath + "[" + numOfKids + "]"
        childHandle = json_data + parentPath + "[" + numOfKids + "][handle]"
        assert 'handle' in childPath
        handleItem = childHandle
        print("Child : " + handleItem)
    else:
        print("Done")
```

When calling the function using:

```
validateChildren(json_data, "['contents']['rootFeature']['childFeatures']")
```

I receive an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'str'*
```

I've tried a few other ways to convert the inputted values, but I am stumped on making it work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: print("Child : " + str(handleItem))

Comment: Trying to manually handle json like this is painful, error-prone and generates spaghetti code. Use any of the tons of good json libraries, or `dpath` like @abamert suggests. Read the [`json` help](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) for starters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just take a fragment of Python code like `"['contents']['rootFeature']['childFeatures'']"` and append it to an object and expect it to work as if you'd used the code.

On the very rare occasions where you really do need to do that, you can build a string out of the entire expression and call `eval`—but this isn't one of those very rare occasions.

What you're actually trying to do is apply a "key path" to a nested dict. The best way to do that is something like this:

```
def validateChildren(json_data, parentPath):
    item = json_data
    for key in parentPath:
        item = item[key]
    # then use item
```

validateChildren(json_data, ('contents', 'rootFeature', 'childFeatures'))

If you're trying to do anything more complicated, like getting a list of all `json_data['contents'][:][:]`, or accepting a path as a string from the user rather than building it up out of string variables you already have separately, you may want to look at something like [`dpath`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dpath) (or, if you're dealing with Cocoa stuff rather than internet stuff, maybe a KVC library), but for simple cases like yours, just iterating or recursing over the keys is all you need.